# Array management and preview with Laravel Livewire

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7, laravel-livewire

When using an input file to load images with Livewire I found that if the user clicks to load multiple images it works correctly, but if he clicks on the same input a second time, the previews with Livewire are replaced by the selected images. second time. To solve this add an array that loads the images as follows:

**My input file**

```
<input wire:change="cargaImagenes" wire:model="imagen" type="file" name="imagen" accept="image/*" class="form-control-file" multiple>
```

**Event Charge**

```
public function cargaImagenes()
        {
            foreach ($this->imagen as $ima) {
                array_push($this->imagenes, $ima);
            }
        }
```

The problem is that I do the previews of the images with Livewire in the following way:

```
 @if ($imagenes)
           <small>previsualización:</small>
    
           <div class="form-inline">
             @foreach($imagenes as $img)
              <div wire:key="{{$loop->index}}">
              <div class="m-2 img-thumbnail">
                <img class="my-2 rounded img-fluid contenedor-img" src="{{ $img->temporaryUrl() }}">
                  <button class="btn btn-outline-danger" wire:click="eliminarImagen({{ $loop->index }})">
                  </button>
              </div>
              </div>
             @endforeach
             <br>
            </div>
      @endif
```

And the problem is that they don't show the first time I select images, it shows when I add more.

For the preview I use the $images property of the array

```
 array_push($this->imagenes, $ima);
```

Can you give me a suggestion of what I could do to display all the images in the array.

Comment: Just curious. I wasn't aware of the wire:change directive. So I googled and only mention I have found at Livewire docs is this sentence: Example usage: wire:change="setSomeProperty($event.target.value)"
Maybe trying wire:change="cargaImagenes($event.target.value)" would bring some interesting results? Haven't tested.

Comment: It does nothing, thanks anyway. What I see is the array does not load the first selection of images. When loading the second, it loads the first selection and not the current one. How curious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work.

Remove wire:change completely.

```
<input wire:model="imagen" type="file" name="imagen" accept="image/*" class="form-control-file" multiple>
```

Hook on the updatedImagen() event method:

```
public function updatedImagen()
{
    foreach ($this->imagen as $ima) {
        $this->imagenes[] = $ima;
    }
}
```

Comment: May you have many blessings. Infinite thanks works perfect !!